# Does dropout layer go before or after dense layer in TensorFlow?

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, neural-network, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

According to [A Guide to TF Layers](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/layers#building_the_cnn_mnist_classifier) the dropout layer goes after the last dense layer:

```python
dense = tf.layers.dense(input, units=1024, activation=tf.nn.relu)
dropout = tf.layers.dropout(dense, rate=params['dropout_rate'], 
                            training=mode == tf.estimator.ModeKeys.TRAIN)
logits = tf.layers.dense(dropout, units=params['output_classes'])
```

Doesn't it make more sense to have it *before* that dense layer, so it learns the mapping from input to output with the dropout effect?

```python
dropout = tf.layers.dropout(prev_layer, rate=params['dropout_rate'], 
                            training=mode == 
dense = tf.layers.dense(dropout, units=1024, activation=tf.nn.relu)
logits = tf.layers.dense(dense, units=params['output_classes'])
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It is not an either/or situation. Informally speaking, common wisdom says to apply dropout after *dense* layers, and not so much after convolutional or pooling ones, so at first glance that would depend on what exactly the `prev_layer` is in your second code snippet.

Nevertheless, this "design principle" is routinely violated nowadays (see some interesting relevant discussions in [Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/MachineLearning/comments/42nnpe/why_do_i_never_see_dropout_applied_in/) & [CrossValidated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/240305/where-should-i-place-dropout-layers-in-a-neural-network)); even in the [MNIST CNN example](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/keras-2/examples/mnist_cnn.py) included in Keras, we can see that dropout is applied both after the max pooling layer and after the dense one:

```python
model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(32, kernel_size=(3, 3),
                 activation='relu',
                 input_shape=input_shape))
model.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
model.add(Dropout(0.25)) # <-- dropout here
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(128, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))  # <-- and here
model.add(Dense(num_classes, activation='softmax'))
```

So, both your code snippets are valid, and we can easily imagine a third valid option as well:

```python
dropout = tf.layers.dropout(prev_layer, [...])
dense = tf.layers.dense(dropout, units=1024, activation=tf.nn.relu)
dropout2 = tf.layers.dropout(dense, [...])
logits = tf.layers.dense(dropout2, units=params['output_classes'])
```

As a general advice: tutorials such the one you link to are only trying to get you familiar with the tools and the (very) general principles, so "overinterpreting" the solutions shown is not recommended...